# Python Syntax errors detected on an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, raspberry-pi, neopixel

i'm trying to run my code but i've been stuck for hours on a syntax error. I've tried diffrent if statement levels, rewriting the part, etc... nothing changes. Anyone has any idea? thanks

I've used online chackers too but with no results.
I run the code using Python 3, can't run it with older versions.

The error happens on all the lines of this part of the code:

```
if alarmdown == 1:
        bright = bright - 1
        pixels.fill((brightmaxred, 0, bright)
        if bright == 10:
                alarmdown = 0
elif alarmdown == 0:
        bright = bright + 1
        pixels.fill((brightmaxred, 0, bright)
        if bright == brightmaxblue:
                alarmdown = 1
```

Here's the full code, it's a RGB strip timer

```
import time
import board
import neopixel
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18, 24)


#variables
terminate = 0
startup = 1
bright = 1
selectpix = 0
goblue = 0
pixelstart = (0, 0, 100)
order = 1
timerexpired = 0
alarmdown = 1

brightmaxblue = 20
brightmaxred = 30

currentlow = 0
currenthigh = 23

#set timer speed
totaltime = 15 #how many seconds? approximation
timetotal = totaltime / (brightmaxred * 30)

#set a clean board
pixels.fill((0, 0, 0))

#if til true
while terminate == 0:
        if startup == 1:
                goblue = goblue + 1
                pixels.fill((0, 0, goblue))
                time.sleep(timetotal)
                if  goblue == brightmaxblue:
                        startup = 0
                        timer = 1
        elif startup == 0:
#start from the pixel no. 0 - 23 - 1 - 22 - ...
                while timer == 1:
                        pixels[selectpix] = (bright, 0, brightmaxblue)
                        bright = bright + 1
                        time.sleep(timetotal)
                        if  bright == brightmaxred:
                                if currentlow == 12:
                                        timer = 0
                                        timerexpired = 1
                                elif selectpix == currentlow:
                                        selectpix = currenthigh
                                        currentlow = currentlow + 1
                                elif selectpix == currenthigh:
                                        selectpix = currentlow
                                        currenthigh = currenthigh - 1
                                bright = 0
                if timerexpired == 1:
                        if alarmdown == 1:
                                bright = bright - 1
                                pixels.fill((brightmaxred, 0, bright)
                                if bright == 10:
                                        alarmdown = 0
                        elif alarmdown == 0:
                                bright = bright + 1
                                pixels.fill((brightmaxred, 0, bright)
                                if bright == brightmaxblue:
                                        alarmdown = 1
```

Comment: You mention "an error" several times. Please add the full Traceback – it tells us *much* more than that "an error occurred".

Comment: If you are new to Python (or programming in general). **please** use a proper IDE (such as PyCharm or VS.Code) instead of a text editor. They will help you catch bugs such as this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pixels.fill((brightmaxred, 0, bright)
```

You've got two left parentheses and only one right.